# Is it possible to backup live SQL data files with SpiderOak

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

This is a hypothetical question.

We have a couple of smaller (less than 3GB) SQL Server databases. What could go wrong if the data and log files were added to SpiderOak backup while keeping the database running?

Would it make a difference if the backup frequency was not real-time but for example every XX minutes?

The goal would be to have a close to real time backup in place with SpiderOak's versioning in place.

Answer (score 0):

Third party backup software needs to use the SQL Server VDI API(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175536.aspx) in order to backup SQL Server files while the database is running.  Unless the backup software is uses the necessary APIs, you may end up with database backups that cannot be used for restore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. My question was really meant as a thought exercise. I would never plan actually using the approach. :)